# Python Beautiful Soup Webscraping: Cannot get a full table to display

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to python and this is my first web scrape. I am trying to scrape a table and can only get the first column to show up. I am using the find method instead of find_all which I am pretty sure what is causing this, but when I use the find_all method I cannot get any text to display. Here is the url I am scraping from: https://www.fangraphs.com/teams/mariners/stats
I am trying to get the top table (Batting Stat Leaders) to work. My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

htmlText = requests.get('https://www.fangraphs.com/teams/mariners/stats').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, 'lxml', )
playerTable = soup.find('div', class_='team-stats-table')
input = input("Would you like to see Batting, Starting Pitching, Relief Pitching, or Fielding Stats? \n")


def BattingStats():
    print("BATTING STATS:")
    print("Player Name: ")
    for tr in playerTable.find_all('tr')[1:55]:
        tds = tr.find('td').text
        print(tds)

if input == "Batting" or "batting":
    BattingStats()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list-comprehension to get text from all rows:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


playerTable = soup.find("div", class_="team-stats-table")


def BattingStats():
    print("BATTING STATS:")
    print("Player Name: ")
    for tr in playerTable.find_all("tr")[1:55]:
        tds = [td.text for td in tr.select("td")]
        print(tds)


BattingStats()
```

Prints:

```
BATTING STATS:
Player Name: 
Mitch Haniger 30 94 406 25 0 6.7% 23.4% .257 .291 .268 .323 .524 .358 133 0.2 16.4 -6.5 2.4
Ty France 26 89 372 9 0 7.3% 16.9% .150 .314 .276 .355 .426 .341 121 0.0 9.5 -2.6 2.0
Kyle Seager 33 97 403 18 2 8.4% 25.8% .201 .246 .215 .285 .416 .302 95 -0.3 -2.9 5.4 1.6

...
```

---

Solution with `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/teams/mariners/stats"

df = pd.read_html(url)[7]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 Name  Age     G    PA   HR  SB    BB%      K%    ISO  BABIP    AVG    OBP    SLG   wOBA   wRC+  BsR   Off   Def  WAR
0       Mitch Haniger   30    94   406   25   0   6.7%   23.4%  0.257  0.291  0.268  0.323  0.524  0.358  133.0  0.2  16.4  -6.5  2.4
1           Ty France   26    89   372    9   0   7.3%   16.9%  0.150  0.314  0.276  0.355  0.426  0.341  121.0  0.0   9.5  -2.6  2.0
2         Kyle Seager   33    97   403   18   2   8.4%   25.8%  0.201  0.246  0.215  0.285  0.416  0.302   95.0 -0.3  -2.9   5.4  1.6

...
```